# linux execute binary file by full path

Tags: linux, binary, executable

I have an executable file `ffmpeg` in `/home/juping/`. If I change my working directory to `/home/juping/` with the command `cd /home/juping/`, I can run the executable file `ffmpeg` by running `./ffmpeg`. If I do not change the working directory, can I then still run the executable file by its full path like `.//home/juping/ffmpeg`? I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: It should be just `/home/juping/ffmpeg`. But this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow which is a site for programming questions. Question may be appropriate for [Superuser](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can execute it by typing

```
/home/juping/ffmpeg
```

Comment: It works, Thanks.

Comment: the . is only needed when you execute something from your current work directory.
You could do  ./home/juping/ffmpeg when your in the root /

Answer (score 3):

The ./ point to current directory.